# Android -- Gallery.onItemSelected() causes scrolling to snap

Tags: android

I have a Gallery with arrow indicators that show whether there are images to the left or right.

```
      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
          <com.package.views.MyGallery
            android:id="@+id/carGallery"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:spacing="2dip"
            android:fadingEdge="none" />
          <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/prev"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/left_orange_arrow"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip" />
          <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/right_orange_arrow"
            android:paddingRight="25dip" />
      </RelativeLayout>
```

I update the arrows as such:

```
carGallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, final int position, long id) {
        Car car = carAdapter.getCar(position);
        top.setText(car.nickname);
        bottom.setText(car.year+" "+car.make+" "+car.model);

        if(carAdapter.getItems().size() == 1) {
            prev.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if(position == 0) {
            prev.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(position == carAdapter.getItems().size()-1) {
            prev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            prev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Any time I change the visibility of an arrow, the Gallery snaps to the item that just scrolled in to selection.  I know that Gallery.onItemSelected() is causing the snapping because when I do Gallery.setCallbackDuringFling(false), it doesn't do the snapping on a fling until the final item is selected.

What can I do to stop Gallery from snapping like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of links that address a similar problem, though it may not be the same as yours:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16171

[Weird animation on Gallery when a invalidate is requested from it's children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527006/weird-animation-on-gallery-when-a-invalidate-is-requested-from-its-children/9127406#9127406)