# How to prevent gallery snap to page when lazy-loading (asynchronous) images

Tags: android, image, asynchronous, gallery, lazy-loading

I got a big problem, I used [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) to implement lazy loading on a base adapter on a galery that displays views with some text and a image. The gallery is paging enabled and it has the fling system disabled.

```
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

If I start scrolling and the next view has a image in it the gallery will reset itself  when the image loads (it will snap/page to the view witch occupies the most of the screen). The gallery is unusable, you have to fling pretty hard so that you get to the next view before the image loads and the reset happens. 
I've implemented a button system to switch to the next view for now but I need to fix this fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [Weird animation on Gallery when a invalidate is requested from it's children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527006/weird-animation-on-gallery-when-a-invalidate-is-requested-from-its-children)

What we did was cache images and load them if available, if not then load them with an `AsyncTask`.  But if that does not work for you, a solution from that question may.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, seems to be what I need, I'll check it out.